# React Native Webview - injectJavascript not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm trying to inject JS code to alert the user before the content of the React Native Webview loads, however, for me it just goes to the activity indicator and loads the Webview without injecting any Javascript. How do I fix this? Code below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import styles from '../../styles';

export default function Links() {

  function LoadingIndicatorView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.hubLoading}>
        <ActivityIndicator color='#009b88' size='large' />
      </View>
    )  
  }

  const runFirst = `
      setTimeout(function() { window.alert('hi') }, 2000);
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `

  return <WebView source={{ uri: https://www.google.com/ }} renderLoading={LoadingIndicatorView} startInLoadingState={true} javaScriptEnabled={true} injectedJavaScript={runFirst} />;
}
```

Btw, I am running the app on my iOS device if that helps you to answer.

Comment: Can my answer help you? If yes, please accept the answer. If no, please provide more information for us to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include `onMessage={(event) => {}}` in the `WebView`

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md

> An onMessage event is required as well to inject the JavaScript code into the WebView.

```js
<WebView 
      source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com/" }}
      renderLoading={LoadingIndicatorView}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
      onMessage={(event) => {}}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, how do i pass a value from my react native app to my webview. eg. i have a session id created when i press a button to open the webview, now i need to access that session id inside my webview for configuration.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={injectedJavascript}
```

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/4d8a76f3691479ef22b55e05c07921af99332395/docs/Guide.md#loading-local-html-files

Comment: This worked for me. I had onLoad function inside my script