# React-native-WebView setItem() from localStorage no working

Tags: react-native, local-storage, react-native-webview

The page I want to open at React Native app requires checking the `localStorage`, which stores the `user token`, `user roles`, and `user permissions`. Therefore, it is necessary to set the token and other relevant values in the `localStorage` before loading the page.

I use the prop `injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded` in `react-native-webview` but didn't work.

**Here is my code**

```js
const runFirst = `
      window.localStorage.setItem('api_token', 'zzz');
      window.localStorage.setItem('auth_roles', 'zzz');
      window.localStorage.setItem('auth_permissions', 'zzz');
      setTimeout(function() { window.alert('hi') }, 1000);
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `;

    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <WebView
                startInLoadingState={true}
                source={{
                    //uri: 'https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview',
                    uri:'xxxxxx'
                }}
                injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={runFirst}
                onMessage={(event) => {}}
                style={{width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight}}
            />
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
```

**The code**

```js
setTimeout(function() { window.alert('hi') }, 1000);
```

will be execute but the

```js
window.localStorage.setItem
```

didn't be execute.

and the page be opened is blank.

If I remove the code about `window.localSotrage.setItem` , the page be open will be normal.

Device: Samsung Galaxy A34 5G
OS: Android
OS version: android 9
react-native version: 0.71.13
react-native-webview version: 13.6.2

I have tried and read the resource about React-Native-WebView injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded:

- [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078060/react-native-set-localstorage-in-webview)
- [issue about injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1609)
- [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67428517/react-native-webview-injectjavascript-not-working)

I looking for some solution or help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waiting until the document is loaded before accessing `localStorage`?

```js
    window.onload = function(){
      window.localStorage.setItem('api_token', 'zzz');
      window.localStorage.setItem('auth_roles', 'zzz');
      window.localStorage.setItem('auth_permissions', 'zzz');
      setTimeout(function() { window.alert('hi') }, 1000);
    }
```

Maybe the alert works because of the timeout.